# Rails 3. Change redirection upon form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have this table where you add taxes.

```
|Name | Rate | Description |
|IVA  |  16  | something   |
|     |      |             |
|     |      |             |
|     |      |             |
save
```

So if  you hit save, it will save the new items entered. I had to do this in taxes_controller.rb

```
@account = Account.find(current_user.account_id)
3.times {@account.taxes.build}
```

Then this in the form

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
<table style="width:400px;" class="taxes">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Rate</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>

<%= f.fields_for :taxes do |builder| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= builder.text_field :name %></td>
    <td><%= builder.text_field :rate %> %</td>
    <td><%= builder.text_field :identification %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
...
```

When I submit the form, the fields do get saved in the database. The problem is that it redirects to the Account show page; and I understand it has to do that because of `form_for(@account)`.

So the question is: how can I specify where I want the form to redirect after submission. In this case, I want to redirect it to the currect page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's only indirectly because of `form_for(@account)`.

When you post your form, it hits the create (or update) action of the accounts_controller.

So it's in these 2 actions (create and update) of this controller that you should do a `redirect_to ...`.

You say that you want to redirect to the current page. What is the current page exactly?

---

Ok, so what you can do is add this to your routes:

```
resources :accounts, :module => "taxes"
```

And your form would become

```
form_for [:taxes, @account] ... do |f|
```

Your controller would be in `app/controllers/taxes/accounts_controller.rb`

```
class Taxes::AccountsController < ::AccountsController
    def edit

    end

    def update
        ...
        redirect_to taxes_url
    end
end
```

So you'd have to change your form with this method. You could pass the path ([@account] or [:taxes, @account]) as an argument of your partial...

Another solution, maybe simpler, would be to just have a redirect_to input in your form. You set it only when you use your form in taxes. And in the controller, `unless params[:redirect_to].blank?; redirect_to params[:redirect_to] end`...

Comment: yes but i also use the account controller to create new accounts. but in the form above, i only use it to create new taxes. the current page is http://localhost:3000/taxes

Comment: I think in the accounts_controller you meant `class Taxes::AccountsController < AccountsController`, right? without the `::`? So I changed that but then got another error: `undefined method `tax_accounts_path` error in this line `<%= form_for [:taxes, @account] do |f| %>`

Comment: No, I meant `::AccountsController`. I like to have the `::` to be specific that I want to "root" AccountsController. Anyways. Maybe try to replace the routes with :scope to `namespace :taxes do; resources :accounts end`.